# Testing an activity and pass an extra?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent, guice, roboguice

I am writing a test for my activity

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
activity.onCreate(null);
```

my activity expects and extra parameters to be passed, so when I call onCreate it crashes.
How can I pass an extra to my activity without using an Intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have the activity under test use some default values for the extra parameters, but I don't recommend that approach.  Instead, just have the test pass in the values.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html#setActivityIntent(android.content.Intent)

> Call this method before the first call to getActivity() to inject a customized Intent into the Activity under test.

Comment: I created an intent and passed it to my activity. myActivity.setIntent(myIntent);